# Custom Sized Table View Still Using Offset For Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am making a viewController that to input information `Name (UITextField)` `Desc (UITextView)` and then add time slots for each task (TableView) however when I add the viewController to my navigation Controller it adds an offset to the `UITableView` as if it were suppose to fill the page.

I have tried changing the offset but that only results in moving the massive white space further up the page and another white space appears below (I'm assuming its from the tab bar controller). how can I get rid of this offset?

[image: Why is offset Wrong]

Comment: Judging from the screenshot you are on iOS 7. Have you tried setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` in your view controller? Depending on the circumstances, this can also be useful: `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`. [Here is an overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html) of these properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do the following:

- Frame your tableView to occupy full view frame.
- Use `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` to reduce the actual table size to the proper size. In your case make sure top edge for contentInset and scrollIndicatorInsets are equal to the size of your textview and textField.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with an apple example they wrap their add a tableViewController to a UIView by adding the tableViewController as a childViewController of the UIView or if you are using storyboard u can use the container view